# How can i add item in sql using jquery(ajax) via web service

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a web service and inside it two methods (`select`, `insertdata`). I want to insert a record in sql using jquery. How can i do this? I have already make that code but it's not working. Please help me out.

**My web service**

```
Sqlconeection dd = new Sqlconeection();
int rowsInserted = 0;
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string  insertRecord(Int64 mbn,string name,double amt,bool Notify)
{
    SqlConnection connection = dd.getconnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertData");
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        connection.Open();
   // string inser = "insert into expensive(mobileNumber,Name,Amount,Notify)values('" + mbn + "','" + name + "','" + amt + "','" + Notify + "')";
    //cmd.CommandText = inser;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile", mbn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", amt);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notify", Notify);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    rowsInserted= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return string.Format("Thank you, {0} number of rows inserted!", rowsInserted);
}
[WebMethod(Description = "Returns all Products")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public DataTable selectdata(Int64  mnb)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection conn = dd.getconnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Open();
    string select = "select mobileNumber,Name,Amount,Notify from expensive where mobileNumber='" + mnb + "'";
    cmd.CommandText = select;
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dt.TableName = "expensive";
    dt.Load(dr);
    return dt;

}
```

**My API code**

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        var mob = $('#txtmo').val();
        var Nm = $('#txtName').val();
        var amout = $('#txtAmt').val();
        var notify = $('#txtnoty').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "InsertData.asmx/insertRecord",

            data: "{ mob: '" + mob + "', Nm: '" + Nm + "',amount:'" + amout + "',notify:'" + notify + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = data.d;
                if (obj == 'true') {
                    $('#txtmo').val('');
                    $('#txtName').val('');
                    $('#txtAmt').val('');
                    $('#txtnoty').val('');
                    $('#lblData').html(JSON.stringify(data.d));
                }
            },
            error: function (r) {
                console.log(r);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide some more details, and show as snipped of code, not whole program.

Comment: Your data object property names don't match those of your webmethod for a start.

Comment: Also in your success you check if a 'true' is returned from the webmethod but it actually returns a success message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a ScriptService attribute to the web service class:

```
[ScriptService]
public class InsertData : WebService
```

Then replace your javascript with this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        var mob = $('#txtmo').val();
        var name = $('#txtName').val();
        var amout = $('#txtAmt').val();
        var notify = $('#txtnoty').is(':checked');

        var submission = {
            'mbn': mob,
            'name': name,
            'amt': amout,
            'notify': notify,
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "InsertData.asmx/insertRecord",

            data: JSON.stringify(submission),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#txtmo').val('');
                    $('#txtName').val('');
                    $('#txtAmt').val('');
                    $('#txtnoty').val('');
                    $('#lblData').html(data);
                }
            },
            error: function (r) {
                console.log(r);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: its not working . give me another solution. tell me one think .is it necessary to add web service reference or not in client side ..

Comment: Is the page that is calling the service in the same directory as the service itself?

Comment: I have updated the solution above, I've tested this and it definitely works.

Comment: i have for textbox(mobile, Name,Amount,Notity) . i will be pass value like(8989898,Raj,8000,True). not checked . please help me out why its working .

Comment: Notity field is not a check box button . its is a text field . i will be pass value as true or False only .

Comment: Yes service page are same directory

Comment: Did you add the [ScriptService] attribute to the web service class? I think the only other things I did was make the attributes on the web method all lower case (I think notify is capitalised in your example).